# Is it possible to use a machine learning library with streaming inputs and outputs?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to incorporate machine learning into a project ive been working on but i havent seen anything about my intended use case. It seems like the old pandoras box project did something like this but with textual input and output.
I want to train a model in real time as well as use it (and then switch it from testing to live api endpoints when it works well enough.)
But every library ive found works like "feed in a datablob, get an answer"
I want to be able to stream data into it:
instead of giving it "5,4,3,4,3,2,3,4,5" and it says "1" or "-1" or "0"
I want to give it "5" then "4" then "3" then "4" etc and each time it responds.

Im not even sure if "streaming" is the right word for this. Please help!

Comment: What's stopping you from just putting in the inputs one at a time?

Comment: It doesnt depend on the single input but it depends on the patterns in the inputs. And im kind of an efficiency nut (which conflicts with my interest in machine learning) ... I dont want to have to send 1000 values each time when 999 of them are repeats (because of pci latency)

Comment: I guess i should add "im willing to invent the wheel but i dont want to reinvent the wheel if its already there" so an acceptable answer is "that doesnt exist" and then i will make it exist in a few months.

Comment: Ok, if your outputs are dependent upon previous inputs, then an RNN is the way to go (add an LSTM or a GRU layer to your network). EDIT: As Hans has just pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a usecase for [recurrent neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), which translate sequences (your stream) into single outputs or other sequences. This is a well-explored approach, e.g., in natural language processing. [Tensorflow has support](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) for different flavors of such nets.

Comment: This makes sense. I was thinking "it seems like such a common use case, why cant find?" Well the answer is (as i thought) im using the wrong word because im new to machine learning where the slangcabulary (slang * vocabulary = slangcabulary) is different. Updoot.